# Can't curl without port 80 open, but port 80 shows as open anyway

Tags: iptables, firewall, curl

So I made a apache server and put a page up, and it should be accessible on port 80 (so default), and I should be able to curl it.

Apache listens on port 80 (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf)

But when I try to curl it from outside, it gives me a random error:

```
me@me:~$ curl myaws
curl: (7) Failed to connect to myaws port 80: No route to host
```

(myaws is my aws instance that has port 80 open, it's an aws ec2 instance).

So this output is from myaws:

```
[me@here yes]# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4394/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4580/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4538/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      10003/httpd         
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      4580/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      4538/master         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           3829/dhclient       
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           3457/chronyd        
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                3457/chronyd
```

But the weird thing is, if I do this following command, then it suddenly accepts my curl:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 --syn -j ACCEPT
```

But even after this command, `netstat -tulpn` gives me the same output.

So I honestly don't understand this... Also this command does not persist, if I do `sudo service firewalld restart`, then I cannot curl it again until I do the iptables command again...

Comment: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Saving_Iptables_Firewall_Rules_Permanently

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I have the proper security groups, it allows 80 inbound from anywhere.

Comment: Also that first link does not tell me what's wrong with it, and why the iptables rule does not show up on `netstat -tulpn`. Also `service iptables save` does not work...

Comment: @user361193 Why not just open the port via `firewall-cmd` with `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp` and then `firewall-cmd --reload`? If `firewalld` is running then you don't need to use `iptables`. After those commands, you can see port 80 open in `firewalld` with `firewall-cmd --list-ports`.

Comment: netstat showing the port open doesn't open that port in the firewall. iptables rules are transient, firewalld only maintains its own rules.

Comment: I think you should add the result of this command in the question: `iptables -L -nv`